# index on column which is only used for IS NULL and IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, null, indexing

I have a column *deleted* in my table. On every sql statement I check whether this *flag* IS NULL. Does someone want to delete entries, the flag is set to the current timestamp.

In case to restore entries, this timestamp is used to restore them. This is the only use case when the value of this column will be used.

In all other cases, it's only important to know whether it IS NULL or it IS NOT NULL.

In the future the table can and will contain millions of rows.

Is it useful to create an index on this column? Because 99% of the statements & use cases don't care about the value.
Does MySQL optimize IS NULL conditions and therefore an index is not needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An index on 'deleted' will also index null values, and thus allow for faster lookups of non-null/null

I think this will be sufficient in this case and not cause too much overhead, since the timestamp is set on deletion, and therefor won't be changed all that much. (The opposite: using an edit-timestamp that is changed all the time and only sometimes set to null, would cause adjusting the index on every time a record is changed. That might not be optimal. That is not the case here.)

(Also, but I don't know if the indexer is smart enough to take advantage of that, the expected changes always go to the ends of the index, either at the null-end or at the 'most recent' end.)

Of course, profile (both query execution times and storage space if important) to find out if there are actual problems arising from this.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you create an "archive" table and store deleted rows with their timestamp. 
If the user want to restore a row, you juste have to transfer it from archive to your main table.

And you don't have to check "flag IS NOT NULL" in every query

Comment: This is an extremely naive suggestion. You'd break all foreign keys or have a serious headache replicating it all in the archive tables. You'd also get a different primary key from the sequence on undelete, which would break any existing URI's unless you exclusively use slugs.

Answer (score -1):

1. According to this book ([High Performance MySQL, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101718.do)) it does not recommended to use "allow NULL" in columns definition in MySQL. MySQL use additional byte to store status of cell (Null or not Null) and index size will be bigger than without "allow NULL". Better solution to make row TINYINT datatype and store value 1 for active rows and 0 for deleted rows. So it is recommended to never use allow NULL in column definition.

Comment: Additional space is needed, yes. But what about the speed? Is it faster to check for IS NULL or to check = 0? Or is this only a marginal optimization?

Comment: Never use NULL? What about importing data into a column that needs to be 1 or 0 but you also need to know if no value were ever present? NULL exists for a reason and should be used when it make sense. Not using NULL can cause serious problems when checking for data integrity, especially on text columns that could contain blank spaces. I always use NULL as a default value unless there is some compelling reason not to use it.